# cron job zip up a directory and email the contents

Tags: linux, cron

I am trying to zip up a directory and have the contents emailed to me. How could I do this?

I have a cron setup for mysql backup which ends like:

```
 | gzip | uuencode public_html_backup.gz | mail example@mail.com
```

Would I be able to perform a similar thing for zipping a directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To back up `/path/to/parent/directory`, you can use

```
cd /path/to/parent && tar -cjf - directory | uuencode | mail -s "directory backup on $(date)" address@example.com
```

This uses bzip2 compression. If you prefer gzip compression (uses less CPU but compresses less), replace `-czf` by `-cjf`. If you prefer zip format, replace `tar -czf - directory` by `zip -r - directory`.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know your entire command but yes it would work, for example:

```
uuencode fileA.zip fileB.zip | mail -s "My Mail Subject" example@mail.com
```

another example:

```
tar cvf - Folder | gzip > my_backup.tar.gz | uuencode my_backup.tar.gz | mail -s "Subject" example@mail.com
```

another example:

```
gzip -c somefile.tar | uuencode somefile.tar.gz  | mail -s "My Backup" example@mail.com
```

You could use mutt aswell:

```
mutt -a file.tar.gz -s "subject of message" example@mail.com
```

[**For a more complete guide click here!**](http://www.shelldorado.com/articles/mailattachments.html)

Comment: Thank you also for this - I wish I could accept two answers

Comment: @Malachi Soord np aslong as you got it working, its all good :)

Comment: It actually took a combo of both your solutions to get what I required